Refactoring T-SQL to Databricks SQL to return results from Subquery
I have the following T-SQL that when I attempt to execute with Databricks SQL I get the error

Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'rn'

I have a view called db.myview and it would appear Databricks SQL is unable to execute the sub-query for rn (at least that is what I think)
SELECT * 
FROM
(select 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID order by ID),
*
    from db.myview c
) c
where c.rn = 1

When I execute the above query in SQL Server I have no problems.

"Refactoring" does not mean adapting or translating a query for another RDBMS...

Spark SQL requires the column alias to come after the column expression.

named_expression
An expression with an assigned name. In general, it denotes a column
expression.
Syntax: expression [[AS] alias]

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select.html
So
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C_NAME order by C_CUSTKEY) as rn, *
    from CUSTOMER c
) c
where c.rn = 1

